# What is the best way to save this relation in Django?

Tags: python, django, m2m

Let's imagine we are creating a site, where people can sell anything to other people.

For example, we have two categories: Computers and Cars

We have some filters for categories: Memory, CPU, Mileage, Color

And we have values for these filters: 4GB, 8GB, AMD, Intel, 0-9999, 10000+, Brown, Black (people cannot just type their own values, they have to select them from a list)

Example Django code:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=30)


class Filter(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=30)


class FilterValue(models.Model):
    filter = models.ForeignKey(Filter, db_index=True)
    value = models.CharField(_('Filter value'), max_length=30)
```

So, filters related on categories, filter values related on filters. Now we have our tables:

categories:

```
id | name
------------------
 1 | Computers
 2 | Cars
```

filters:

```
id | name
------------------
 1 | CPU
 2 | Memory
 3 | Mileage
 4 | Color
```

categories-filters:

```
id | category_id | filter_id
-----------------------------
 1 |           1 |         1
 2 |           1 |         2
 3 |           2 |         3
 4 |           2 |         4
```

filter_values:

```
id | filter_id | name
-----------------------------
 1 |         1 | Intel
 2 |         1 | AMD
 3 |         2 | 4GB
 4 |         2 | 8GB
 5 |         3 | 0-9999
 6 |         3 | 10000+
 7 |         4 | Brown
 8 |         4 | Black
```

And now here comes the question - how should I make the Item model?
Example code:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField(_('Price'))
```

But how to link it to filters and filter values properply in Django? I can create two Many2Many relations, but it will create **3 databases**. However, it needs only **two**:

item:

```
id | category_id | name
------------------------------
 1 |           1 | My computer
 2 |           2 | My car
```

item-filter-filter_value:

```
id | item_id | filter_id | filter_value_id
------------------------------------------
 1 |       1 |         1 |               2
 2 |       1 |         2 |               3
 3 |       2 |         3 |               5
 4 |       2 |         4 |               8
```

So now in DB two items: My computer with AMD CPU and 4GB memory and My car with mileage 0-9999 and black color.

Which way is the right way to implement this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [customize the many-to-many table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) to match your suggested table. In your example it might look like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField(_('Price'))
    filters = models.ManyToManyField(Filter, through='ItemFilter')

class ItemFilter(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    filter = models.ForeignKey(Filter)
    value = models.ForeignKey(FilterValue)
```

Just pay attention to the docs about how to access the through model fields and how this changes the related manager.

Comment: Yep, that's what I want. Thank you!